# Is it possible to show previous month and next month dates in the current Month of android.widget.CalendarView in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using `android.widget.CalendarView` and it only shows current month dates and display empty spaces. Example attached screenshot below. So is there any way to display previous and next month dates in the empty spaces?[image]

At the beginning I want to fill the empty spaces with previous month dates S, M , T and at the end W, T, F, S with next month dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly recall, the *old* CalendarView (you're using) used to support this as well, but it's been a few years since I used that one, as I have been relying on Material Design 1, 2, and now 3, for a while.

The days that do not belong on the currently displayed month are called "Outside month dates" [source](https://m3.material.io/components/date-pickers/specs) according to Material Design 3.

While the calendar defaults to show you only the current month, it's my understanding (but I didn't actually test this) that by supplying a `CalendarConstraints` instance that includes other days, the date picker will display them (and, at least in Material 3, they can be styled differently as they have their own attributes).

**All that being said**, the [current documentation for the DatePicker in GitHub](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/DatePicker.md), does **not** mention `Outside of month` at all in the specs or APIs of the DatePicker component, and it is **my guess** that if you supply a constraint with dates in the past that those dates will be displayed.

If you need help with that [Here is the CalendarConstraints](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/datepicker/CalendarConstraints) API.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought old calendar view does not support Outside month dates in Api level 24 and above , but thank you for sharing links though